# Remove (duplicate) failed TestNG result via rerun tests

Tags: testing, testng

I added rerun test by Testng, but have a problem with duplicate tests in test report. Could you help me with this

```
private int retryCount = 0;
private int maxRetryCount = 1;

@Override
public boolean retry(ITestResult result) {
    if (retryCount < maxRetryCount) {
        System.out.println("Retrying test " + result.getName() + " with status "
                + getResultStatusName(result.getStatus()) + " for the " + (retryCount+1) + " time(s).");
        retryCount++;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public String getResultStatusName(int status) {
    String resultName = null;
    if(status==1)
        resultName = "SUCCESS";
    if(status==2)
        resultName = "FAILURE";
    if(status==3)
        resultName = "SKIP";
    return resultName;
}
```

And

```
public class RetryListener implements IAnnotationTransformer {

@Override
public void transform(ITestAnnotation testannotation, Class testClass,
                      Constructor testConstructor, Method testMethod)   {
    IRetryAnalyzer retry = testannotation.getRetryAnalyzer();

    if (retry == null)  {
        testannotation.setRetryAnalyzer(iOpiumListener.class);
    }

}
```

}

But in test report displayed or two failed or one passed and one failed test

Answer (score 1):

Olga, I believe that you're missing additional listener that will clean your test results:

```
public class TestListener implements ITestListener {

    @Override
    public void onTestStart(ITestResult result) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTestSuccess(ITestResult result) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTestSkipped(ITestResult result) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTestFailedButWithinSuccessPercentage(ITestResult result) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(ITestContext context) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish(ITestContext context) {
        Set<ITestResult> failedTests = context.getFailedTests().getAllResults();
        for (ITestResult temp : failedTests) {
            ITestNGMethod method = temp.getMethod();
            if (context.getFailedTests().getResults(method).size() > 1) {
                failedTests.remove(temp);
            } else {
                if (context.getPassedTests().getResults(method).size() > 0) {
                    failedTests.remove(temp);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, please, be aware of the fact that it'll work only with pure `TestNG`, case you have additional tools that rely on `TestNG`, i.e. `Cucumber` - It'll be necessary to clean those reports separately.

Comment: Is there an approach when we are using DataProvider for a Test method and running with multiple data set? And then we are re-running failed methods. Because in this case by default there will be multiple result object for a test method.

Answer (score 0):

You can catch results which are incorrect  (onTestFailure) and delete them when all the tests are done (onFinish)

```
 
public class RetryAnalyzer implements IRetryAnalyzer {
```

```
   private static int retryCount = 0;
   private static final int maxRetryCount = 1; 
   private static boolean isRerun = false;

   @Override
   public boolean retry(ITestResult result) {

      if (retryCount < maxRetryCount) {

          retryCount++;
          isRerun = true;
          return true;
      } else {
          retryCount = 0;
          isRerun = false;
      }
      return false;
  }

  public boolean isRerun() {
      return isRerun;
  }

  private String getResultStatusName(int status) {
      String resultName = null;
      if (status == 1)
          resultName = "SUCCESS";
      if (status == 2)
          resultName = "FAILURE";
      if (status == 3)
          resultName = "SKIP";
      return resultName;
  }
```

}

public class TestListener implements ITestListener, IAnnotationTransformer {

private List<ITestResult> failedTestsToRemove = new ArrayList<>();

  @Override
  public void onTestStart(ITestResult result) {
  }

  @Override
  public void onTestSuccess(ITestResult result) {
  }

  @Override
  public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {
      RetryAnalyzer retryAnalyzer = (RetryAnalyzer)  result.getMethod().getRetryAnalyzer();

      if (retryAnalyzer.isRerun()) {
          failedTestsToRemove.add(result);
      }
  }

  @Override
  public void onTestSkipped(ITestResult result) {
  }

  @Override
  public void onTestFailedButWithinSuccessPercentage(ITestResult result) {
  }

  @Override
  public void onStart(ITestContext context) {
  }

  @Override
  public void onFinish(ITestContext context) {
      for (ITestResult result : failedTestsToRemove) {
          context.getFailedTests().removeResult(result);
      }
  }

  @Override
  public void transform(ITestAnnotation testannotation, Class testClass, Constructor testConstructor,
                      Method testMethod) {

      IRetryAnalyzer retryAnalyzer = testannotation.getRetryAnalyzer();

      if (retryAnalyzer == null) {
          testannotation.setRetryAnalyzer(RetryAnalyzer.class);
      }
  }

}